# spring-amqp vs rabbitmq version

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Is there a matrix or mapping that identifies the versions of rabbitmq that can be used with each version of spring-amqp?  We are currently using rabbitmq 3.5.4 with spring-amqp 1.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such spring-amqp version as 1.0.2.

If you mean 1.2.0, even that is over 3 years old and there have been many releases since then.

You can generally use older spring-rabbit releases with newer brokers (and even newer java client libraries), but you won't get access to any of the newer features.

Similarly, you can use newer spring-amqp releases with older brokers (at least as far back as 2.8), but again, you don't get access to the newer broker features.

But no; there's not a matrix.

The current release of spring-amqp is 1.5.1.

Comment: Yes, sorry, 1.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: Our only position statement is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/_introduction.html#compatibility). If you find some compatibility issue that we can fix with a non-breaking change, we'll do our best to do so. However, it would probably only be included in a 1.5.x and 1.4.x (and maybe 1.3.x if we're pushed).